# Mapping Toolbar with dropdown options

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, data-driven-pages, toolbar

I had this option available to me at a previous job, and I have been trying to recreate it for sometime to no avail.  I was trying the custom tool bar route/model builder/ data driven pages route to no avail.

Basically it is tool bar with dropdowns where the user first selects the feature class, then they select the year (a field in the feature class), then they select the name of the job.  Then the user has the one record of interest zoomed to, so they can print off a map.

An example would be like this:

1. Select the feature class-> the dropdown options would be "logging" or "tree planting", etc.
2. Select the year (which a field in the logging or tree planting feature class)-> the drop down options would be "2015", "2016", etc
   3.Select from a list of jobs associated with first two options-> ie you could see all the tree planting jobs from the year 2015 and select one.

I would consider myself an intermediate GIS user, but I have a feeling that this tool was made by a power user(s) at my previous job.

Answer (score 1):

This does not sound like an out-of-the-box tool and so I think that you would need to develop it.

This type of application is one that I think people will usually refer to as "maps on demand".

If I were developing it I would use a Python Script Tool, with tool validation for the pick lists, and an ArcPy cursor on an index feature class rather than using ModelBuilder or Data Driven Pages.

Whoever developed your previous toolbar may have done so as a Python AddIn but much of the code would be similar.

Comment: I wrote a similar tool in VB6, it was a lot of work and I don't think the value was ever recovered in time saved; much of the time was invested in creating nicely formatted excel spreadsheets of the focus data so perhaps it would be viable if the reporting was skipped. I worked with definition queries on the layer(s) which was then zoomed to visible extent of features. I might add VB6 support predates data driven pages; with some python, as you say, and data driven pages it might be workable but the code would be significant, too much for GIS.SE focused question/answer format.